# what is the difference between selectors and locators in selenium webdriver?

Tags: automated-testing, selenium-webdriver

I want to know the names of  different locators that are used in selenium web driver, what if someone asks me to write down the selectors and write them in order from fastest to slowest

Comment: Does this https://www.quora.com/What-is-the-difference-between-CSS-selector-and-Xpath-in-selenium answer your question?